# How to hide ribbon in Calendar Item display form in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, calendar, ribbon, display-form

I need to hide the painting part for all users except two or three people in the admin group.

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Is it SP 2010?!

Comment: https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/27/how-to-hide-ribbon-in-sharepoint-2010-using-css/

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS or JQ to make a REST call to endpoint `/_api/web/currentUser`. This endpoint gives some information about current logged in user. It contains a property `IsSiteAdmin`. You can check, if the `IsSiteAdmin == true` then hide/remove the `#s4-ribbonrow` DOM element. Note that this property will be true for `Site Collection Admins`. If you are having a custom SP group named as `Admin`, then you need to fetch the login user groups, check it belongs to admin group and hide/remove DOM element.

**Edit: Code**

```
<script>
    function checkUserInGroup(groupName){
        var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups/getByName('"+ groupName +"')/Users?$filter=Id eq " + _spPageContextInfo.userId
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json,odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function(data){
                if(data.d.results.length == 0){
                    // User is not in group.
                    // TODO
                }else if(data.d.results == 1){
                    // User belongs to group.
                    //Hide the ribbon, button or whatever is required.
                }
            },
            error: function(error){
                // May be group is not present/invalid.
            }
        })
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Can you clarify more please?  or send me the link. Thanks

Comment: can you confirm you want to show ribbon to site administrator or a SP group named 'admin'

Comment: The above form is a registration form. It can be accessed by any user with contribute permission. I need to prevent current login user who are contractor not to submit the form. THAT MEANS PREVENT THEM FROM REGISTERING. "pop up message and then close the form.

Comment: are those contractor belongs to a particular SP/AD group?

Comment: Definitely true

Comment: i had edited the ans, with the required code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61767/discussion-between-thinkb4code-and-sara).